# Select timestamp with time zone, but ignore seconds

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp-with-timezone

I'm selecting a `timestamptz` from a PosgreSQL database.

I want my `SELECT` to return only the date, hours and minutes. No seconds. Can I set the date format in my psql `SELECT` to accommodate this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use [**`date_trunc()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) to truncate seconds and still return a `timestamptz`:

```
SELECT date_trunc('minute', ts_col) ...
```

Or you can use [**`to_char()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) to return a formatted timestamp as `text` any way you like:

```
SELECT to_char(ts_col, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') ...
```

Note that this will format the `timestamptz` according to your current time zone setting. Details:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

Answer (score 0):

With timezone:

```
SELECT date_trunc('minute', TABLE_NAME.COLUMN AT TIME ZONE '+03') FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are many ways to handle this, but the efficient way is to use `date_trunc`, as mentioned in the privous answer.

An alternative pproach is to use `to_char` function.

Example

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(timestamp_column, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') AS formatted_ts
FROM table_name;
```